# Tizen Controlling the TV Using a Pointing inside my app

Tags: tizen

Hello guys i'm currently developing an app in tizen SDK for tizen TV.

I want to create a pointing inside my app so i can use only the Remote control, something like in this picture

https://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/figure/img_03_19_pointing.png  (that blue dot it's like a mouse pointer on the PC)

Can someone please share some source on how to do this.

THank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this, be aware that **the remotes for 2016 TVs no longer support the pointing functionality**.  Be sure you also support navigation with just the [basic input keys](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenUxGuide/03/03_input_method.html#ux-03).

From samsungdforum's UX guidelines on [Input Methods](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenUxGuide/03/03_input_method.html#)

> Because the Smart Remote is constantly evolving, buttons and features other than the basic buttons are subject to change. Hence, in order to make applications that are not restricted by a locale or the TV model, only use the basic buttons described in 3.1.1..